# MPAndroidChart Multi-Color YAxis

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

sorry about my english.

I'm creating an app with charts, i'm using MPAndroidChart but i need set the Y Axis with different colors and it only accept one. The color depends of the data (it's dinamic)

Can someone help me?

it's something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpyyr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is **not supported by default**. You will have to modify the library to your needs to achieve this functionality.

Comment: thanks, what i did was create a combined chart with the first xAxis with multicolored bars and a line chart... pretty rough but it work.

thanks for the awesome library!